# Hashtable: why is get method synchronized?

Tags: java, hashtable, synchronize

I known a `Hashtable` is synchronized, but why its `get()` method is synchronized?

Is it only a read method?

Comment: Because it needs to be synchronized with the put methods.

Comment: I don't understannd.There is only one class field--table need synchronized,but get method no write operation?

Comment: Both the `put` and `get` operations have to be synchronized with each other...and they are.

Answer (score 16):

If the read was not synchronized, then the Hashtable could be modified during the execution of read. New elements could be added, the underlying array could become too small and could be replaced by a bigger one, etc. Without sequential execution, it is difficult to deal with these situations.

However, even if `get` would not crash when the Hashtable is modified by another thread, there is another important aspect of the `synchronized` keyword, namely cache synchronization. Let's use a simplified example:

```
class Flag {
  bool value;

  bool get() { return value; } // WARNING: not synchronized
  synchronized void set(bool value) { this->value = value; }
}
```

`set` is synchronized, but `get` isn't. What happens if two threads A and B simultaneously read and write to this class?

```
1. A calls read
2.                 B calls set
3. A calls read
```

Is it guaranteed at step 3 that A sees the modification of thread B?

No, it isn't, as A could be running on a different core, which uses a separate cache where the old value is still present. Thus, we have to force B to communicate the memory to other core, and force A to fetch the new data.

How can we enforce it? Everytime, a thread enters and leaves a synchronized block, an implicit [memory barrier](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) is executed. A memory barrier forces the cache to be updated. However, it is required that both the writer and the reader have to execute the memory barrier. Otherwise, the information is not properly communicated.

In our example, thread B already uses the synchronized method `set`, so its data modification is communicated at the end of the method. However, A does not see the modified data. The solution is to make `get` synchronized, so it is forced to get the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in Hashtable source code and you can think of lots of race conditions that can cause problem in a unsynchronized `get()` .

(I am reading JDK6 source code)

For example, a `rehash()` will create a empty array, and assign it to the instance var `table`, and put the entries from old table to the new one.  Therefore if your `get` occurs after the empty array assignment, but before actually putting entries in it, you cannot find your key even it is in the table.

Another example is, there is a loop iterate thru the linked list at the table index, if in middle in your iteration, rehash happens.  You may also failed to find the entry even it exists in the hashtable.

Comment: I agree with you,but I am not sure,so ask.

Answer (score 0):

`Hashtable` is synchronized meaning the whole class is thread-safe

Inside the `Hashtable`, not only get() method is synchronized but also many other methods are. And particularly put() method is synchronized like Tom said.

A read method must be synchronized as a write method because it will make sure the visibility and the consistency of the variable.

Comment: This is nonsensical.  Hashtable is a class and you can't declare a class to be `synchronized`.  And indeed, `Hashtable` is not entirely thread-safe.  (In particular, iteration is not thread-safe in the way that you might expect ...)

Comment: @StephenC I agree with what you said after reading [thread-safe](http://vanillajava.blogspot.hk/2011/06/thread-safety-issues-with-vector-and.html) Thanks!